# Writing a float to a BLE characteristic. What data format?

Tags: bluetooth, python, data-type

I am currently working on a python-based Bluetooth Low Energy client for OS X and I got stuck while trying to write a remote float characteristic value.

First of all: my setup is an Arduino 101 with integrated BLE module and a Macbook. On the Arduino side the code is working well, I can read and write BLE characteristic's from a BLE explorer app on my phone.

Also I did achieve to read out the characteristics float values in my python script on the Macbook. Yet I did not fully understand what exactly I am doing. After requesting the characteristic's value from the peripheral, the peripheral answers and I get what I think is binary data? I could manage to unpack the data to a float by using.

```
     def characteristic_to_float(data):
        float_value = struct.unpack('f', data)[0]
        return float_value
```

The received floats are correct. But I couldn't get my python code to properly write a float value to the peripheral. I tried this:

```
    a_number = 5.3

    def float_to_characteristic(float_value):
        val = struct.pack('<f', float_value)[0]
        return val

    characteristic_1.write_value(float_to_characteristic(a_number))
```

The python code itself will run through without an error, but the Arduino doesn't receive the data. I am sure of that, because I implemented a function on it that sends out a Serial print when a characteristic has been written.

Remember the characteristics are read & write and I could verify this by using my phone. I think I got something wrong with the struct.pack thing, since I can't find any information about what data format is needed...

Does someone know how I can pack or convert the float to the right data format? Unfortunately the lib I use (Adafruit BluefruitLE) does not have a documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: Try packing and then unpacking the value entirely in python as a test.  Try sending the packed value from the arduino back to it directly as a test.  Figure out how to dump the bytes of the packed value as hex from python for verification, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the issue by taking another look in the documentation of the struct lib in python. I tested different pack and unpack methods and wondered where the [0] in my code came from (I did copy it from somewhere). So what I found working for my setup simply is:

```
def float_to_characteristic(float_value):
       val=struct.pack('<f',float_value)
       return val
```

When I send this packed value through BLE the Arduino will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions came to my mind if am gonna do your thing,
1) convert the number to a string char by char and send it as it is then unpack it as char by char , for example 5.3 -- > "5.3" it will be received then you have to decompose it 5 and . and 3 (inefficient solution because of conversion of types will be alot)

2) calculate the number of decimal digits and send it with the number something like:
5.3 ---> 53 and one decimal point, you would send it as 
53:1 and then unpack it and reconstruct it

the second solution would be better for me since i have to send it as 2 things 
number: decimal point
and then reconstruct it, this library will ease the reconstruction of decimal point sent by 53:1 (if you want to send floats in two directions)
[SimpleSerialExtractor](https://github.com/Mohamad1994HD/SimpleSerialExtractor.git)

Answer (score 0):

I used this way:
define a BLE format descriptor (0x2904)
Attach the descriptor to the characteristic

```
struct BLE2904_Data {
  uint8_t m_format;
  int8_t m_exponent;
  uint16_t m_unit;
  uint8_t m_namespace;
  uint16_t m_description;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct BLE2904_Data desc1;   // must remain valid memory for ArduinoBLE


  desc1.m_format = 0x14;  // float
  desc1.m_exponent = 0x0;
  desc1.m_unit = 0x2728;  // voltage
  desc1.m_namespace = 1;
  desc1.m_description = 0x10f;

  BLEDescriptor voltageLabelDescriptor("2904", (uint8_t*)&desc1, sizeof(desc1));
  batteryLevelCharacteristic.addDescriptor(voltageLabelDescriptor);
```

The 2904 descriptor sets the data type see [here](https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-numbers/Assigned%20Number%20Types/Assigned_Numbers.pdf) for more details: